# Grafana regular expression

Tags: java, regex, grafana

I am working on grafana and try to find a regular expression which can match any of the below scenario.

```
1) values can be of format fg-elastic-*
2) values can be of format fgelastic-*
```

I am trying the regex

```
/fg[-|elastic-]+.*/
```

But the issue here is it matches only the second one along with some other values like

```
fgxxxx-redis-*
```

which I don't want. Can you please help me with this scenario ?

Comment: A suitable regex could be `/fg-?elastic-/`. You might want to check for conditions on the start of the match (eg. preceding space).

Comment: `fg-?elastic-.*` should work, just do not use `/` chars on both ends.

Answer (score 0):

In regex [•••] represents a [character class](https://regular-expressions.mobi/charclass.html?wlr=1), not a group.  A character class matches any **one** of the characters in the brackets, and most special characters, like the pipe, are considered as literals.

I suspect you want `/fg(-|elastic-){1,2}.*/`. Alternatively you could use `fg-?elastic-.*` since you have the one optional character `-`.